# How do I show WooCommerce products with a given category based on user login or not

Tags: wordpress

I have a client with the following issue:

I need to be able to split their WooCommerce WordPress site into essentially two way login user and without login. If a user is logged in then there will category list form, user selected that category then store that category against user table and only products in the category get pulled from the database.

However if the user is not logged in then same form of category will be there but now we want saved that category into session nd accordingly that selected category value we need to fetch product.

I figure I'll add something like this to the theme's functions.php file:

add_filter("some_woocommerce_hook", "wholeseller_filter");

```
function wholeseller_filter() {
    if (logged-in-user){
        //omit products without "wholesale" category while browsing whole site
    } else { 
        //omit products with "wholesale" in the category while browsing whole site.
    }
}
```

I've browsed around StackOverflow, but I haven't found what I'm looking for or quite know what keywords I should be using for my searches.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is the form created ?

Comment: @Bhanu i created form . Logged-in user working fine. Not getting how to handle not logged-in user?

Comment: What you need to do is, on form submit you have to save the category `id` or `slug` into WooCommerce session like this `WC()->session->set( 'user_preferred_category' , $cat_id );` . Now you can asses this by `WC()->session->get( 'user_preferred_category' , $data );`. 

You then have to use `woocommerce_product_query` to alter the query and restrict product for the `id` you have in  `user_preferred_category`. See this : https://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-modifying-product-query/

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the function `is_user_logged_in` could solve the problem.

```
function wholeseller_filter() {
    if (is_user_logged_in()){
        //omit products without "wholesale" category while browsing whole site
    } else { 
        //omit products with "wholesale" in the category while browsing whole site.
    }
}
```

For more info about the function, you could navigate:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/